# jQuery Ticker - Move controls/nav from right to left

Tags: jquery, news-ticker

I'm trying to use the jQuery News Ticker (from jquerynewsticker.com). The location of the controls/navigation is on the right. I tried to move it to the left (before the news item) and thought it'd be possible to do through editing the CSS, but it looks like the controls are created in the jquery file and beyond what I know... Could you help?

jquery file is here: *www.jquerynewsticker.com/includes/jquery.ticker.js* and 
CSS file is here: *www.jquerynewsticker.com/styles/ticker-style.css*

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.left .ticker {float:right;}
.left .ticker-controls {padding-left:0; padding-right:6px;}
```